# Replace all but a set of characters in a file with newline

Tags: linux, sed, awk, perl

how to delete all characters in file except numbers and "." , 
 each word (numbers/dot)  should  be in new line in file see example2

- the solution can be with  sed or awk or ksh syntax

remark - the solution must be according to the example 2

example 1

file before edit

```
  192.0.22.1++0.1
  e32)5.500.5.5*kjcdr
  ##@$1.1.1.1+++jmjh
  1.1.1.1333
  33331.1.1.1
  @5.5.5.??????
  ~3de.ede5.5.5.5
  1.1.1.13444r54
  192.9.30.174
  &&^#%5.5.5.5
  :5.5.5.5@%%^^&*
  :5.5.5.5:
  **22.22.22.22
  172.78.0.1()*5.4.3.277
  3.3.3ki.3.
```

example 2 of file after delete all characters except numbers and "." charter , each new word will be in new line

```
  192.0.22.1
  0.1
  32 5.500.5.5
  1.1.1.1
  1.1.1.1333
  33331.1.1.1
  5.5.5.
  .
  5.5.5.5
  1.1.1.13444
  54
  192.9.30.174
  5.5.5.5
  5.5.5.5
  5.5.5.5
  22.22.22.22
  172.78.0.1 
  5.4.3.277
  3.3.3 .3.
```

Comment: Your sample output is a bit inconsistent.  Why are `32` and `5.500.5.5` both on line 3?  Why is there no `3` (from `3de`) between the lines for `5.5.5.` and `.`?  Why are `3.3.3` and `.3.` both on the last line?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like [this question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/448925/30957) -- did you not get a good answer there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) use case, so the simplest way is:

```
tr -cs '[:digit:].' '[\n*]' < input > output
```

The `[:digit:].` argument specifies the characters to match (digits and dot).  The `[\n*]` specifies the characters to replace with (replace everything with newline).  The `-c` option inverts the first argument since we want everything except digits and dot.  The `-s` squeezes consecutive newlines from the second string into one.

Answer (score 1):

grep can do it:

```
grep -o '[0-9.]\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace any unwanted character to a newline, and then `grep` to get rid of empty lines:

```
sed 's/[^0-9.]/\n/g' | grep .
```

Note that the result is different from the one you posted: `32 5.500.5.5` is split to two lines, as well as the last line.

Perl solution: it splits each line on unwanted characters, and greps for nonempty lines.

```
perl -ne 'print "$_\n" for grep /./, split /[^0-9.]+/'
```

Comment: Note that `\n` above in the `sed` command example is not standard. The standard syntax to specify a newline character in the RHS of a `s` command is with a backslash followed by a new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':a;{N;s/[^\.0-9]\+/\n/g};ba' file
```

Here's how it works:

1. Create a branch label;
2. Append current/next line to register;
3. Branch if not last line;
4. Replace all groups that aren't matching with newlines.

Using the branch avoids spurious newlines.

Answer (score 0):

on RHEL7:

replace any line starting with VALUETOEDIT

```
sed -i -e 's/^VALUETOEDIT.*/NEWVALUE/g' somefile
```